# Add multiple pages to a pdf with pdfmake

Tags: node.js, pdfmake

I have a situation where I need to add multiple pages to a single document using pdfmake.
The scenario is that a user would send a list of IDs representing a database entity to a REST endpoint.  The code then retrieves data from a database given those IDs and generates a PDF for each of those IDs.  Those individual documents would then be added as pages to a compiled PDF document.

Right now this is the code I have:

```
 for (var index in ids) {
   context.log("Generating PDF for ID: " + ids[index]);
   const pdf = await PdfGenerator.generatePDF(JSON.parse(templateStr));
   pdf.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dir+fileName, {flags: 'a'}));
 }
```

This is how the generatePDF method looks

```
public static async generatePDF(docDefinition: any): Promise<any> { 
    const pages = [];
    const fontDescriptors = {
        Roboto: {
            normal: path.resolve("./fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
            bold: path.resolve("./fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf"),
            italics: path.resolve("./fonts/Poppins-Italic.ttf"),
            bolditalics: path.resolve("./fonts/Poppins-MediumItalic.ttf"),
        },
    };
    const printer = new pdfMakePrinter(fontDescriptors);
    const doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        doc.end();
        resolve(doc);
    });
}
```

So in essence the PDF is generated and then piped to a file.  This file can then later be read and sent back to the user in a response.  When I run this, the file is created and appears to have data in it, but the PDF is blank when viewed.  What am I missing?